# How to Push vector pair value in 2d vector?

Tags: c++, vector, key-pair, 2d-vector

Suppose I have a `vector<pair<int,int>> v`, the values are in `v` is `{[1,3],[3,7],[8,9]}`. I want to store them in `vector<vector<int>> vv`.

How can I do this?

I try to store them in `vector<vector<int>> vv` but I can't solve this

Answer (score 1):

You can convert ***vector of pairs*** to ***vector of vectors*** by using a for-each loop.

```
for (auto& pair : v) // loop through 'each' pair inside the vector of pairs
    vv.push_back({ pair.first, pair.second }); // convert the pair to a vector and add it to the vector of vectors
```